# Why do USB Keyboards work instantly in DOS / BIOS but have to install drivers in Windows?

Tags: usb, drivers, keyboard

For example, if you're at your BIOS screen or a DOS environment, when you plug in a new USB keyboard, it appears to be usable almost instantly. But, if you are in Windows and plug in a new keyboard, it has to install drivers or updates, making it unusable for the duration. I realize that you don't get full features of certain keyboards in DOS, so Windows has to install drivers for added functionality. But why doesn't the keyboard start working with basic functionality instantly and continue to install the rest of the drivers if needed, obviously the technology is there to make this happen.

This is more for curiosity than to solve a problem, but any insight is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Everything you need to know is in that link

Comment: That's what I was looking for, didn't find that when I searched, appreciate it!

Comment: Note: Legacy PS/2 and AT style keyboards need drivers in Windows too.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate because the other question doesn't ask why its so slow in Windows! The reason why its slow in Windows is: Windows will do a lot of stuff when a device is connected for the first time. It will search for what's the best driver for the device, create a restore point (slow!), install the driver and finally start it. The BIOS OTOH only has to start (initialize) its driver, which takes almost no time for such a simple driver. Re-connecting a mouse or keyboard (to the same port) on Windows also just requires starting the driver, which is why it's also very fast.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, that is just the "style" how windows works. In BIOS there are the basic-functions available. But as you said, there are special functions who need the drivers.

So I think windows don't "trust" the user to use the keyboard until the driver is installed. It's the same with for example the iphone. I've plugged it in to the PC by the USB-cable. Nothing happened, until the driver was installed. Even it wasn't charged.

But as I said, I think its the style of windows.

Comment: This isn't a very helpful it's just your viewpoint on how Windows works but very little of it is actually correct. Furthelre my personal experience there isn't a delay when using an USB keyboard which was plugged in at boot time

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I interpreted "but any insight is appreciated" false. I thought that means something like "any thinking about it" etc.

Comment: feel free to backup your answer with support documentation otherwise it a comment